# Creating restful API with Redis and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, sortedset

I am trying to create server to process REST API and redis sorted set.
And the post score API is not working well and I don't know why.
Can anyone help me?

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var redis = require('redis');
var app = express();
var JSON = require('JSON');
var client = redis.createClient(6379,'127.0.0.1');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}))

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('connected 3000 port!');
});

app.post('/score', (req, res)=>{
  var id=req.headers.id;
  var score=req.headers.score;

  client.zadd('score', id, score, function(err, reply){
    if(err){
      res.send(false);
    }else{
      res.send(true);
    }
  });
})
```

This is curl I used.

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "id:hi" \
   -H "score:9223372036854775807" \
   -d \
'' \
 'http://localhost:3000/score'
```

Comment: This is not a really secure (never trust the clients)...

If `id` is the id of a user: one user could affect the score of other users by modifying the `id`, or submit fake score information.

I tested it without `redis` and the server receives the headers correctly with that post sample, so the problem must be in the `client.zadd`... why dont you console.log the err and/or the reply to get more info?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I also think zadd is not working, bcs it seems like it gets id or score information correctly. But redis data never changes and it always returns 'false'.

Comment: @EMX Thank you so much, it was simply a problem of input order of 'score' and 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

## Regarding ZADD :

I believe it would be something like the following snippet :
([node_redis documentation](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#commands-with-optional-and-keyword-arguments))

```
var args = [ 'score', score, id ] 
client.zadd(args,(error,response)=>{
 if (err) throw err
 console.log('added '+response+' items.')
})
```

More information : [ZADD - Redis Documentation](https://redis.io/commands/zadd)

---

## Regarding Security for Games :

I still suggest that some protection is added server-side to prevent unwanted tampering with your scores...

I understand that many games that are single player experiences simply offer a post to scoreboard approach, but you have to know that if the score is not accompanied by some sort of protection mechanism, you cannot guarantee it hasn't been tampered with... hence you are open to *cheaters* modifying their scores and other peoples scores...

It is also important to note that unless its an authorative server where everything is being calculated server-side and the clients acts simply as a renderer and requester for actions (for the server to evaluate) you will be in some way open to *cheating*, since you can really **never trust the clients**.